# Recording multiple browsers in a single run in Cypress

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress

I'm trying to configure Gitlab CI to make it work with Cypress. In general everything starts, Cypress works itself. The problem appears with [Cypress Dashboard](https://dashboard.cypress.io/). Basically iy works - tests are recorded correctly. The only issue is, I wanna test my app on two browsers - Chrome and Firefox. Cypress records both browsers in two separate runs:

[image: One run per one browser]

I know that I [can't run both of them in the same time](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-browsers-open-at-the-same-time). But I wanted to use grouping functionality (or something) to "merge" `runs`.

Another thing that suggests me that grouping both browsers in one run could be possible, is this filter in test results:

[image: Tests results]

This is my job definition:

```yaml
End-To-End:
  stage: e2e
  parallel: 2
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - dist/cypress/apps/client/my-app-web-e2e/videos/**/*.mp4
      - dist/cypress/apps/client/my-app-web-e2e/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 7 days
  script:
    - yarn e2e:ci:chrome --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --group "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    - yarn e2e:ci:firefox --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --group "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
```

And `package.json` scripts:

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "e2e:ci": "nx affected --target=e2e --runner=ci --base=remotes/origin/master --parallel --prod --headless",
      "e2e:ci:chrome": "yarn run e2e:ci --browser=chrome",
      "e2e:ci:firefox": "yarn run e2e:ci --browser=firefox"
   }
}
```

I'm using `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA` key for grouping both browsers and groups are created but in separate `runs`.

I was also trying to set `Run Completion Delay` on `cypress.io > Project > Settings > Parallelization` to some high value like `1200`. But that didn't help with my problem.

Alternatively in desperation, I tried to remove all the parallelization, but it works the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed that, but I have just found out that there is something like `--ci-build-id` flag which solves my problem :)

```yaml
variables:
  CI_ID: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA"

...

End-To-End:
  stage: e2e
  parallel: 2
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - dist/cypress/apps/client/my-app-web-e2e/videos/**/*.mp4
      - dist/cypress/apps/client/my-app-web-e2e/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 7 days
  script:
    - yarn e2e:ci:chrome --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --group Chrome --ci-build-id $CI_ID
    - yarn e2e:ci:firefox --record --key $CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY --group Firefox --ci-build-id $CI_ID
```